# EF6 update record result in referential integrity constraint exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a model with many-to-one relationship :

**Class Stock**

```
public class Stock
{
  [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
  [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int StockId { get; set; }

  [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
  [ForeignKey("Description")]
  public string Code { get; set; }

  public StockDescription Description { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [DisplayName("# Shares")]
  public int NumberOfShares { get; set; }

  public void UpdateStock(AddOperationViewModel viewModel)
  {
     this.NumberOfShares += viewModel.NumberOfShares;
     //Get some information from Yahoo!
     Controllers.DetailedInfosStocksController controller = new controllers.DetailedInfosStocksController();
     Models.DetailedQuoteQueryResultModel infos = controller.RetrieveStockDetailedInfos(this.Code);
     FillInfos(infos);
  }

  public void FillInfos(DetailedQuoteQueryResultModel infos)
  {
     if(Description == null)
     {
        Description = new StockDescription();
        Description.Code = infos.Symbol;
        Description.Name = infos.Name;
     }
     Description.FillInfos(infos);
  }
}
```

**Class StockDescription**

```
public class StockDescription
{ 
  [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
  public string Code { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}")]
  [DisplayName("Price")]
  public double LastPrice { get; set; }

  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P2}")]
  [DisplayName("Variation")]
  public double ChangePercent { get; set; }

  public void FillInfos(DetailedQuoteQueryResultModel infos)
  {
     LastPrice = double.Parse(infos.LastTradePriceOnly);
     ChangePercent = double.Parse(infos.ChangeinPercent.Replace("%", "")) / 100;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to update a stock entry as follow :

```
  // POST: AddOperation
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult AddOperation(AddOperationViewModel viewModel)
  {
     if(ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        var existingStock = db.Stocks.Where(s => s.Code == viewModel.Code).FirstOrDefault<Stock>();

        if(existingStock == null)
        {
           Stock stock = new Stock(viewModel);
           db.Stocks.Add(stock);
        }
        else
        {
           existingStock.UpdateStock(viewModel);
           db.Entry(existingStock).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

        return PartialView("StockListPartialView", db.Stocks.Include("Description").ToList());
     }
  }
```

This exception:

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property
>   values that define the referential constraints are not consistent
>   between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

occurs when I set the State of the Entry to be modified. The workaround I've found so far is to set `existingStock.Description = null` but the description is no more updated.

**EDIT**
The `Code` property in the two classes
[image]

Comment: Which property are you using to relate `StockDescription` with `Stock`? Only `Description` on `Stock`, or is there somewhere a `StockId` property in `StockDescription`?

Comment: What does UpdateStock do? does it set the FK properly?

Comment: StockDescription and Stock are related with the `Code` property. And the UpdateStock is given in the sample code and no, it does not change the FK.

Comment: If they are related via the `Code`, then it seems that this property is different of the `Stock` and its `StockDescription`.

Comment: That's what I supposed, but the debugger tells me the opposite, they actually the same (not the same instance, but the same value)

Comment: Could it be that there is something else in the DbContext that might be inconsistent? Or just that one instance?

Comment: Perhaps yes, but how to find it....? That is not the only operation I do on my context, but this one in particular fails

Comment: If you are creating a new `Stock`, you are setting the `Code` you got from `RetrieveStockDetailedInfos` on `StockDescription`, but never on `Stock`. Maybe this is the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102292/discussion-between-guillaumea-and-domysee).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an existing `Stock` you must explicitly replace its `StockDescription`. For this, you need two changes in the code:

```
var existingStock = db.Stocks
                      .Include(s => s.StockDescription) // <= added
                      .Where(s => s.Code == viewModel.Code)
                      .FirstOrDefault<Stock>();

if(existingStock == null)
{
    Stock stock = new Stock(viewModel);
    db.Stocks.Add(stock);
}
else
{
    // Line added:
    db.Entry(existingStock.StockDescription).State = EntityState.Deleted;

    existingStock.UpdateStock(viewModel);
    // Not necessary:
    // db.Entry(existingStock).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

So you must `Include` the existing `StockDescription`. (It isn't loaded by lazy loading because it's not a `virtual` property.) And you have set its state to deleted. Now EF knows it should delete the old description and add a new one.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it, but I dont want to delete the description, just update it as other Stock object might have the same StockDescription

Comment: I'm not sure about this being a 1:n association (as per your edit). The exception uses "principal and dependent", which is 1:1 lingo. Do you have any fluent mappings?

Comment: But maybe it's enough to use the `Include` and not the `EntityState.Deleted`.